# ubuntu 13,10 "Failed to download repository information"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, postgresql

I have ubuntu 13.10- 64 bit version on my machine.recently i tried to install postgres for ROR development but i couldn't complete the postgres installation and found that my update manager always ends with **Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection** eventhough i have **main server** on the server location configuration. i think i would have modify the update manager config file and i tried to revert it back to old but it's not possible.whenever i try **sudo apt-get update** i am getting

```
    W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E585066A30C18A2B
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EF4186FE247510BE
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

error. i went through most of the solution found in stack overflow to revert source.list file but, nothing helped me **so please guide me how to fix this issue? and possibly postgres installtion with phppgadmin** .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have messed up **sources.list** file in your system. Just edit the file using root privileges, i.e,

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And remove all the entries from file. Then paste entries from [here](https://gist.github.com/syst3mw0rm/8163897). I have generated this file using a list generator [site](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) including just major repositories. You might want to add/remove based on your requirements hence generating a new list.

Next, just save it!

And, try `sudo apt-get update` again and it should work by now!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding the key:

   `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E585066A30C18A2B`
2. Update:

   `sudo apt-get update`